# Why I dont see LineString on the map?

Tags: openlayers

Initialization:

```
 this.sourceLineString = new VectorSource();
    this.vectorLineString = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.sourceLineString,
      zIndex: 9000,
      style: new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 2,
        }),
      }),
    }); 

 

 drawLineString(geometry) {
    this.sourceLineString.clear();

    const { coordinates } = geometry;

    let layer = this.mediator.mapRef
      .getLayers()
      .getArray()
      .includes(this.vectorLineString);

    const lineString = new LineString(coordinates);
    const feature = new Feature({
      geometry: lineString,
    });

    this.sourceLineString.addFeature(feature);

    if (!layer) this.mediator.mapRef.addLayer(this.vectorLineString);
  }
```

The coordinates are:

```
[
    [
        37.36371663435188,
        55.36178075525585,
        201.69752926125392,
        37.36364344340238,
        55.36189324268707,
        201.67603986994826
    ]
]
```

There are not errors. Why I can not see lineString on the map?

If to get first two coordinates like this:

```
const lineString = new LineString([
  fromLonLat([37.36359017219166, 55.36186775911044, 0]),
  fromLonLat([37.36370296137778, 55.362064227821314, 0]),
]);
```

It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinates including elevation for a LineString should look like

```
[
    [
        37.36371663435188,
        55.36178075525585,
        201.69752926125392
    ],
    [
        37.36364344340238,
        55.36189324268707,
        201.67603986994826
    ]
]
```

Then if your map view is not EPSG:4326 you must transform the geometry to the view projection

```
const lineString = new LineString(coordinates);
const feature = new Feature({
  geometry: lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', this.mediator.mapRef.getView().getProjection()),
});

this.sourceLineString.addFeature(feature);

if (!layer) this.mediator.mapRef.addLayer(this.vectorLineString);
```